# Problems Storing Encrypted Passwords In MSQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, password-encryption

### My Envirionment:

- System: MacOs 10.17.3 64-bit
- Database: MySQL 8.0 64-bit

### MySQL Settings:

- [image: system variables:]
- [image: table info:]

### My Problem:

I tried to insert an encrypted password into the table with the following
SQL statement

```
    INSERT INTO users
    VALUES ('me@example.com', AES_ENCRYPT('my_password',
    UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')));
```

And I get the following result:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE3Hx5d\xCC...' for
>   column 'password' at row 1

Can anyone shed more light on how I can solve this problem?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. See [tag:password-encryptin] for why not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the character set of your field name to:

```
character set = ascii
```

and

```
collation = ascii_general_ci
```

something like:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtablename MODIFY
    fieldname VARCHAR(60) #depends on your designated max value
      CHARACTER SET ascii
      COLLATE ascii_general_ci;
```